# iPhone app running on iPad has navigation bar back button cropped

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uinavigationbar

I am creating an iPhone app with a navigation bar in it. After I push another view controller the back button shows as expected. But when the screen is rotated to landscape in the second screen, the back button on the navigation bar is cropped like the image below:

[Navbar Cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpgiV.png)

Is there any way to make the navbar not cropped in iPhone compatibility mode?

Comment: Go to project general tab by select target and check Deployment info -> Devices -> it is Univarsal or not ?

Comment: @HardikThakkar no, just iPhone app, because the app is actually built for iPhone only, but since our company doesn't have an iPhone to test, we test it using an iPad

Comment: So don't worry about ipad because of Devices -> it is not Univarsal may be issue is there, you can check in simulator of iphone no need to check in real ipad device.

Comment: @HardikThakkar same results for testing in iPad simulator as shown in the screenshot above. I think Universal should not be selected because the app is actually an iPhone only app...

Comment: Yes, if you don't have iphone device, you can check in iphone simulator it shows same UI like real iphone device. so use iPhone simulator to see UI.

Comment: @HardikThakkar in iPhone simulator the navigation bar works as intended, but as we test it in an iPad, which is the only Apple device that we have (other than Apple computers), the navbar is cropped... Is there any way I can some sort of placing a workaround so that the iPhone compatibility mode on the iPad displays the navbar correctly?

Comment: May be no, but you can ignore that normal UI related points it it shows perfect in iphone. it crop becasue status bar is not visible 20px extra is not in screenshot.